# Python: list grouping

Tags: python

I've got a list with (for example) 100 entries of the sort `['A0', 'B0', 'A1', 'B1', 'A2', 'B2', ... 'A99', 'B99']`.

I'd now like to make this into a list of 50 entries with each entry a tuple `(Ai, Bi)` such that they are grouped together. So the result should be

`[('A0','B0'),('A1','B1'),('A2','B2'),...,('A99','B99')]`. Is there a shortcut to achieve this or do I have to use a loop like

```
for i in numpy.arange(0,100,2):
    newlist.add((oldlist[i], oldlist[i+1]))
```

I'm trying to do quick and advanced programming in python so I'd prefer using shortcuts, list comprehension, ... and not simple for loops where possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the most pythonic way I can think of:

```py
list(zip(oldlist[::2], oldlist[1::2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below should simply it:

```
list_1 = ['A0', 'B0', 'A1', 'B1', 'A2', 'B2']
list_of_groups = [x for x in zip(*(iter(list_1),) * 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want, you can do this:

```
a = ['A0', 'B0', 'A1', 'B1', 'A2', 'B2']
list(zip(*[iter(a)]*2))
# [('A0', 'B0'), ('A1', 'B1'), ('A2', 'B2')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way wiith `numpy`

```
list(map(tuple, np.array(l).reshape(-1, 2)))
#[('A0', 'B0'), ('A1', 'B1'), ('A2', 'B2')]
```

Comment: You don't really need the division — `reshape(-1, 2)` works fine.

Comment: thanks for remembering, I  forgot something basic :) @ Mark Meyer